# java.lang.AssertionError: Comparing error message expected

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng

Both actual and expected values are same still why am I getting assertion error??

Utility.java

```
public  String getValue(String filename, String key) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(".\\testdata\\" + filename + ".properties");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(fis);
    String value = p.getProperty(key);
    return value;   
}
```

errormessage.properties file

> errormessage:× \nError message \nUsername field is required. \nPassword field is required.

Step Definition code

```
@And("^User should get errormessage$")
public void user_should_get_error_message() throws Throwable {
    this.errormessage=this.utility.getValue("errormessage", "errormessage");
    Assert.assertEquals(this.errormessage,this.login.getError(), "Comparing error message");
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Comparing error message expected [×
Error message
Username field is required.
Password field is required.] but found [× 
Error message 
Username field is required. 
Password field is required.]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:190)
    at com.nuance.NHDP.tests.stepdefinitions.nhdplogin.nhdplogin.user_should_get_error_message(nhdplogin.java:105)
    at ?.And User should get errormessage(src/main/resources/features/smoke/clu_reports_administration/clulogin.feature:19)
```

Comment: try removing `[ ]` from the file error message that is what the assertion error said

Comment: errormessage:× \nError message \nUsername field is required. \nPassword field is required - this is my error message file

Comment: try printing both the messages in console then copy both message in notepad and check which character is missing, remove that character from message and make both message exact match before asserting them then assert

Comment: nothing is working for me

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Issue solved

Comment: what was it? and how it got resolved?

Comment: There was an extra space

Answer (score 0):

The second (found) text has ***an extra space** after "Username field is required. " which is not in your expected message.

```
×
Error message
Username field is required.
Password field is required.
```

vs

```
× 
Error message 
Username field is required. 
Password field is required.
```

Comment: What do you get when you do a text compare of both?

Comment: There was an extra space